# Como passar uma lista de valores para um Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, lista, parâmetros, stored-procedures

Estou criando um *stored procedure* no SQL Server 2008 R2 e gostaria de passar uma lista de valores por parâmetro, por exemplo:

Tabela

```
    produto
----------------
| id |  nome   |
| 1  |  maçã   |
| 2  |  pera   |
| 3  |  uva    |
```

*Stored Procedure*

```
create procedure pr_lista_produtos
    @Ids ???????
as
begin

select
    nome
from
    produto
where
    id in (@Ids)

end
```

Para executar eu passaria os ids que eu quero.

```
exec pr_lista_produtos 1, 3
```

Esse *stored procedure* será usado em um projeto feito em `C#`, usando `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` e `SqlDataAdapter`, e os dados serão armazenados em um `DataTable` para exibição em um `DataGridView`.

Minha duvida é como fazer o *stored procedure* receber uma lista de valores, sendo que esses valores irão variar e podem ser 1, 2, 3...N ids.

Comment: MAteus não tem como mandar um array, vc terá que fazer gambiarras, experiencia própria. mandando como varchar igual ao amigo comentou vc tb perde grande perfomance do SQL pq a stored não vai ser mais compilada por causa do execute @query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode passar tabelas como parâmetros.

Primeiramente crie o TABLE TYPE:

```
CREATE TYPE IntegerTableType AS TABLE
(Id INT)
```

Na criação da procedure, você pode utilizar este padrão:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_lista_produtos (@Ids dbo.IntegerTableType READONLY)
...
```

para utilização, no C#, coloque os ids em uma DataTable e passe em um parâmetro "Structured" na execução da procedure, como no exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320891/1627692

Para passar listas com grande quantidade de dados e evitar chamadas repetidas ao banco de dados, esta abordagem me salvou e é facilmente aplicável.

Para ver mais sobre Table-Valued Parameters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: prefira colocar código direto na resposta e depois colocar a referência de origem, isso é bom para temos o conteúdo aqui no SOpt também =)

Comment: Ok Mateus, vou aprendendo a interagir aqui. Valeu.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no [faq](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/699) tem muita coisa que ajuda agora o começo!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize um `VARCHAR` como tipo da variável `@Ids`, a utilização será praticamente a mesma:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_lista_produtos
(
    @Ids VARCHAR(500)
)
AS

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @query = 'SELECT nome FROM produto '
SELECT @query = 'WHERE id IN (' + @Ids + ')'

EXEC (@query)

GO
```

Utilização:

```
EXEC pr_lista_produtos '1, 2, 3'
```

Veja outros meios neste [artigo](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Comment: por se tratar de uma *query* dinâmica, toda vez que ela for executada, ela não será recompilada? Sabe me dizer?

Comment: Consultas dinâmicas também são armazenadas no cache, mas em relação a performance com certeza as estáticas são mais rápidas. Veja os links no SOEn sobre [cache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22701571/4336024) e [dinâmico x estático](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22701571/4336024) @Mateus

Comment: Os dois links apontam para a mesma pergunta.. rsrs.. Sobre o cache, na resposta aceita no SOen, diz que `Query plan won't be cached in #2.` (na *query* dinâmica), é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo completo e comentado de como simular a passagem de um *vetor* ou *array* como parâmetro para uma *Stored Procedure*.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SIMULA_ARRAY_COMPLETA

    @SCOCPFCNPJ             VARCHAR(8000),
    @SCOCLASSIFICACAO       VARCHAR(8000),
    @SDEJUSTIFICATIVA       VARCHAR(8000)

   /* .... OUTROS PARÂMETROS SE EXISTIREM .... */

AS DECLARE  @CPFCNPJ            VARCHAR(14),
        @CLASSIFICACAO      CHAR(1),
        @JUSTIFICATIVA      VARCHAR(255),
        @DELIMITADOR        VARCHAR(2)    

    --Define que vai ser o delimitador
    SET         @DELIMITADOR = '@|' 

    --Inicia a transação 
    BEGIN TRAN  

    --CONCATENA O @DELIMITADOR NO FINAL DE DAS VARIÁVEIS LOCAIS 
    IF LEN(@SCOCPFCNPJ) > 0         SET @SCOCPFCNPJ         = @SCOCPFCNPJ + @DELIMITADOR  
    IF LEN(@SCOCLASSIFICACAO) > 0   SET @SCOCLASSIFICACAO   = @SCOCLASSIFICACAO + @DELIMITADOR  
    IF LEN(@SDEJUSTIFICATIVA) > 0   SET @SDEJUSTIFICATIVA   = @SDEJUSTIFICATIVA + @DELIMITADOR  

    --INICIA LOOP PARA EXTRAIR SCOCPFCNPJ PARA EFETUAR A ATUALZIAÇÃO
    WHILE LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@SCOCPFCNPJ))) > 0
    BEGIN --LOCALIZA E EXTRAI O CNPJ/CPF, @CLASSIFICACAO E JUSTIFICATIVA
            --PARA VARIAVEIS LOCAIS
            SELECT @CPFCNPJ         = SUBSTRING(@SCOCPFCNPJ, 1, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @SCOCPFCNPJ) - 1)
            SELECT @CLASSIFICACAO   = SUBSTRING(@SCOCLASSIFICACAO, 1, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @SCOCLASSIFICACAO) - 1)
            SELECT @JUSTIFICATIVA   = SUBSTRING(@SDEJUSTIFICATIVA , 1, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @SDEJUSTIFICATIVA ) - 1)   


            INSERT INTO NOME DA TABELA (
                    CO_CPF_CNPJ, CO_CLASSIFICACAO, DE_JUSTIFICATIVA) 
            VALUES( @CPFCNPJ, @CLASSIFICACAO, @JUSTIFICATIVA)

            --RETIRA LOCALIZA E EXTRAI O CNPJ/CPF, SITUAÇÃO E JUSTIFICATIVA 
            SELECT @SCOCPFCNPJ= SUBSTRING(@SCOCPFCNPJ, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @SCOCPFCNPJ) + 2, LEN(@SCOCPFCNPJ))

            SELECT @SCOCLASSIFICACAO= 
                        SUBSTRING(@SCOCLASSIFICACAO, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @SCOCLASSIFICACAO) + 2, LEN(@SCOCLASSIFICACAO))

            SELECT @SDEJUSTIFICATIVA = 
                        SUBSTRING(@SDEJUSTIFICATIVA , CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @SDEJUSTIFICATIVA ) + 2, LEN(@SDEJUSTIFICATIVA ))

    END

    --VERIFICA OCORRÊNCIA DE ERROS DURANTE O PROCESSO PARA CONFIRMAR OU NÃO A TRANSAÇÃO 
    IF @@ERROR = 0
    BEGIN COMMIT TRAN
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN ROLLBACK TRAN
    END
```

Considerações:

1. Na camada de apresentação (no ASP por exemplo) pode-se criar os
   array´s normalmente.
2. Na chamada da stored procedure os array´s devem ser transformados em
   string´s delimitadas.
3. Pode-se utilzar qualquer delimitador normalmente utilizo "@|" pois é
   um combinação que provavelmente não vai ser utilizada principalmente
   em campo de descrição e justificativas.
4. No caso de justificativas deve-se ter o cuidado de dividir o tamanho
   total do campo varchar na sp (8000) pelo tamanho da justificativa
   para evitar estouro no tamanho. Exemplo uma justificativa de 255
   poderam ser passadas a 31 ocorrências do vetor (8000/255) caso seja
   necessário passar mais faça um loop na aplicação e passe de 31 em
   31.
5. Para transforma um vetor em string delimitada no ASP pode-se
   utilizar via comando e passar o sVar como parâmetro da sp:

   sVar = join(seu_vetor,"@|")

Esta material foi criado por mim foi criado em 23 março 2007 como um tutorial e pode esta datado, porém acredito que pode ser usado em alguns casos. Claro que deve-ser sempre ser cuidadoso ao utilizar `strings`, pois afeta a performance.

Referência:
[Simula SPLIT (Array) SQL](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/220851-resolvido-simula-array-ou-vetor-sql/)

Comment: esse conteúdo ficaria melhor como um comentário e não como uma resposta, dê uma olhada [nesse link](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42)

Comment: Jota, o problema de respostas contendo somente links é o comprometimento da informação. Se por algum motivo o link quebrar a resposta torna-se inútil. Considere editar sua resposta e incluir as informações que achar importante para futuras buscas e perguntas referentes a esse assunto.

Comment: @rrnan Realmente tens razão. Como o post é de minha autoria vou reproduzi-lo aqui. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Mande tudo em um Varchar e depois execute a query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_lista_produtos
(
    @Ids VARCHAR(500)
)
AS

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @query = 'SELECT nome FROM produto '
SELECT @query = @query + 'WHERE id IN (' + @Ids + ')'

EXEC (@query)

GO
```

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_lista_produtos]
        (
         @IDS   VARCHAR(MAX)
        )
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

create table #ProdutosIDs
(id int)
Declare @ProductsSQL nvarchar(max);
Select @ProductsSQL = 'Insert into ##ProdutosIDs (id) _
    SELECT [id] FROM [produto] WHERE id in (' + @IDS + ')'
exec sp_executesql @ProductsSQL

select  nome
from    produto
where   id in (select ProductID from #ProductIDs)

end
```

Comment: não funcionou, apareceram alguns erros utilizando essa abordagem!

Comment: @Mateus Quais erros? Poderia compartilhá-los?

Comment: Basicamente erro de digitação e confusão de tabela temporária local e global!