# Parametros de entrada em Stored Procedure com mais de um valor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Preciso fazer uma stored procedure no oracle onde tenho 5 parametros de entrada e 1 parametro de saida que será um cursor(recordset). O problema é que cada parametro de entrada pode receber mais que um valor, ou seja, uma lista de valores. Esses parametros recebidos serão usados como filtro na minha clausula WHERE.

Por exemplo, um dos parametros de entrada será o p_customerID e esse parametro podera receber "ID001, ID002, ID003..." e no select do cursor de retorno eu devo filtrar esses IDs:

WHERE
  CUSTOMER in p_customerID

Minhas duvidas:

- Como eu faço para receber uma lista de valores em um unico parametro (no meu caso os 5 parametros de entrada podem receber 1 ou mais valores )
- como eu consigo usar esse parametro no WHERE para filtrar os valores passados como parametro.

obs: Essa procedure será chamada por um sistema externo e recebera o cursor(recordset/refcursor) como retorno.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como passar uma lista de valores para um Stored Procedure?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45738/como-passar-uma-lista-de-valores-para-um-stored-procedure)

Comment: Veja isto https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/parametro-para-sql-com-mais-de-um-valor/322419 na realidade eu achei esta solução no AskTom e não di o crédito nesta página , também em https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/289781-concatenar-valores/